# Remove attribute rel follow from Tag a and replace value nofollow

Tags: php, regex, yii, yii2, htmlpurifier

I would like to remove attribute `rel` following a tag `a` and replace the value with `nofollow` using PHP or Yii2, Regex, or HtmlPurifier.

I use Yii2.

Content:

```
<a href="http://www.hgjhg.com" rel="follow">
<a href="http://www.gggg.com">
<a href="http://www.kjhjg.com/511" rel="nofollow">
```

I would like:

```
<a href="http://www.hgjhg.com" rel="nofollow">
<a href="http://www.gggg.com" rel="nofollow">
<a href="http://www.kjhjg.com/511" rel="nofollow">
```

Comment: any but i think HtmlPurifier good for remove rel follow

Comment: Try it. If you run into problems let us know.

Comment: how to remove attribute rel="follow" with HtmlPurifier ??

Comment: `if (!$code) {print "Where's your code?";}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add nofollow to tag a

```
public static function addNoFollow($html)
{
     $result = HtmlPurifier::process($html, function ($config) {
     $config->set('HTML.Nofollow', true);
     });

     return $result;
}
```